# How to see managed exception details in WinDBG?

Tags: c#, exception, compiler-construction, windbg, sos

VS2005 C# Compiler crashes during our team's nightly build process.  I attach to it with WinDBG, load SOS extensions, print the callstack, but cannot see exception info.

I tried !PrintException, as follows:

```
    0:000> !PrintException
    There is no current managed exception on this thread
```

Here's the top of callstack:

```
    0:000> !CLRStack
    OS Thread Id: 0x9fc (0)
    ESP       EIP     
    0012ee08 77e4bef7 [ComPlusMethodFrameGeneric: 0012ee08] Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Hosting.ICscHostObject.Compile()
    0012ee18 6be671ab Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Csc.CallHostObjectToExecute()
    0012ee48 6c0aed17 Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
```

Comment: !CLRStack saved my hours of issue fixing. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that you found this useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing an exception is that the C# compiler is not written in managed code.  It is a C++ project and hence won't throw a CLR exception.  You need to look for a native error instead.

Answer (score 2):

I got it!  All that needed to be done was to save a dump (*.dmp) file from WinDBG and re-open it in Visual Studio.

For a full solution look at
[my prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835281/how-to-get-a-call-stack-for-an-intermittently-crashing-devenv-com)